# How to find two substrings in a field at the beginning and the end of an array-element in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection in MongoDB which looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "ABCDEFGHIJK",
    "content" : {
        "arrayElements" : [ 
            "BD-cacf99afd87bd536da0162b2246f415e_FH",
            "BD-zhdfcf0bqa12qfT7jl10p9b3276o123p_HUCL",
            "WPG-bklcf10bqa12qg64jl99p9b3276o576a_HUCL",
            "EC-tzlscq10bqa12qg64jl19p9b3475o5z7_FH"
        ],
...
  }
}
```

Additionally, I have two variables (SessionVariables). One of them could contain the first part of the above elements (the part before "-") and the other one could hold the last part (part after the character "_"). For example:

```
Session.set('firstPart', "BD");
Session.set('lastPart', "FH");
```

Now, I would like to perform a query with findOne, which tells me whether any of the above elements contains `Session.get('firstPart')` at the first part until the character `"-"` **AND** `Session.get('lastPart')` after the character `"_"`. If this is true, than please `console.log('One element contains both parts')`.

I thought about `$regex`, but don´t know the right syntax. I need something like this:

```
if (collection.findOne({
      '_id': ABCDEFGHIJK), arrayElements: {
      $regex: /Session.get('firstPart')/ (AND) /
        Session.get('lastPart') / (IN ONE ELEMENT)
    }
  })) {
  console.log('One element contains both parts')
} else {
  console.log('None of the elements contains both parts')
}
```

In this case, where the first variable holds "BD" and the second one holds "FH", the output should be `console.log('One element contains both parts')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`...{"arrayElements": {$regex:val}...`

Declare the string val beforehand as `firstpart+"-.*_"+lastpart`. You didn't clarify if your two variables have the - and _ in them, so I assumed they don't.

Comment: Thanks, I was about to type the answer, because this is exactly what I found out now and it works! Many thanks, this is correct.